# How to get a multiple count inside a select with multiple AND conditions

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, conditional-statements

Im trying to do this count but its returning false ! It only works with just one "AND" condition.

```
public function get(int $id, int $count)
{
    $id5 = $id4 = $id3 = $id2 = $id1 = $id;
    $count4 = $count3 = $count2 = $count1 = $count;
    $sql = "SELECT a.id AS rib_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE table.quem = :id AND table.count = :count) AS Tot,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE table.quem = :id1 AND (table.status = 'Ag' AND table.count = :count1)) AS Tot1,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE table.quem = :id2 AND (table.status = 'Ap' AND table.count = :count2)) AS Tot2 ,
    (SELECT COUNT(id)   FROM table WHERE table.quem = :id3 AND (table.status = 'ComD' AND table.count = :count3)) AS Tot3,
    (SELECT COUNT(id)   FROM table WHERE table.quem = :id4 AND (table.status = 'Re' AND table.count = :count4)) AS Tot4 
    FROM table AS a
    WHERE a.quem = :id5 ";  
    return $this->db->runSQL($sql, [$id, $id1, $id2, $id3, $id4, $id5, $count, $count1, $count2, $count3, $count4])->fetch(); 
}
```

I would like to have an array with all those values counted, with all conditions mentioned.

Comment: Does the `table.count` refer to the `COUNT(id)`, in the sub query, or do you have an actual column called `count`?

Comment: I have another column called count. I use it to get an additional filter.

Comment: If the runSQL method returns false, then it probably encountered some kind of an error while executing the SQL query. You need to share that error message with us.

Comment: This isn't code. This is confusion in the form of code. What are we looking at here? What is it supposed to do? Is there a simpler representation we can help with?

Comment: Only "bool(false)" appears on my screen. I will try to capture the error

Comment: Tip: Build a simpler version that works, then extend it *carefully*. Where practical use functions to generate the various subqueries so you know they're consistent and correct.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the php side , but that code in MySQL can be written more simple as follows:

```
select t.id,
       sum(quem=1 and `count`=1) as Tot,
       sum(quem=1 and status = 'Ag' and `count`=2) as Tot1,
       sum(quem=2 and status = 'Ap' and `count`=3) as Tot1
from my_table t
group by id;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bCRCIZEg)

Comment: That does read way better, at a glance you know exactly what it does.

Comment: @tadman indeed and in term of performance it is much better than the query in the question

Comment: in my database, "quem" and "count" are not numbers (they are words just being used as a filter). in this example, SUM would sum the field total with these filters or do I have to include a new column in the database for the SUM command to count? For example, include a column in all fields with value = 1

Comment: I need to know how many rows I have in the database with these filters applied

Comment: @Jeferson it doesn't matter what "quem" and "count"  are. If all the conditions are true sum will give 1 , if any of the condition isn't true sum will give 0. In simple words it will act like a count.  For example `1+1+0+1+0` will result 3 in the end.

Comment: Thank you all ! I solved the question using the same "select Count" that I had proposed. I replaced $count with the number 1 directly in the condition line, without having to pass it through the function call and it worked.

Comment: Tks Ergest !! I will try with your suggestion too !!